# In Google Spreadsheets, How do you "Order by" QUERY from high to low instead of from Low to High

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

As you all probably know, when you are entering a query such as `=QUERY(B14:J15,"order by C")` into a google spreadsheet, the computer will order the QUERY by Column C, but low to high. I want to know if there is a way to order the QUERY by high to low. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=QUERY(B14:J15,"order by C desc")`

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Order_By